# Query DSL in dev tools returning different results from inside Alert

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an index that I put in some data. All this data is younger than 5 days. When I query this index, I get the expected number of 1373 results:

[image]

Now, I want to set an alert on this index. When the number of results for this query exceeds a threshold, I want to trigger an alarm. However, when I paste this query into an Elastic-query based alert, I get different query results:

[image]

My question: why is this happening, and how to I make the query in the alert return the same amount as in the Query DSL window?

Comment: You use POST or GET ?

Comment: GET in the Query DSL query, I have no idea what the alert uses.

Comment: It s like it is a get, without any data, it s would explain the result.